# .gitattributes match a directory by name in any sub-directory,

Tags: git, gitattributes

In .gitattributes, how can I match any subdirectory with a name `blah`, e.g. `a/blah`, `b/blah`, `c/blah`?

It seems none of:

```
blah -diff
blah/ -diff
blah/** -diff
**/blah -diff
**/blah/ -diff
**/blah/** -diff
```

works.

From `man 5 gitattributes`, I would expect `blah/**` to work:

> The rules by which the pattern matches paths are the same as in .gitignore files (see gitignore(5)), with a few exceptions:
>
> ```
>  •   negative patterns are forbidden
>
>  •   patterns that match a directory do not recursively match paths inside that directory (so using the trailing-slash path/ syntax is pointless in an attributes file; use path/** instead)
> ```

Since `blah/` would work in `.gitignore` and I've changed `/` to `/**` as instructed.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62548768/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitattributes%5D+directory

Comment: @phd I found that too, prior to asking, but it doesn't address subdirs and I couldn't find a solution there.

Comment: The answer explains patterns `sub/*` and `sub/**/*`. In your case it should be `**/blah/* -diff` and `**/blah/**/* -diff`

Comment: Ah! You're right, it was confounded by GitLab only acknowledging the state of the file on master, so doesn't affect the branch it's changed on. Verified with `git check-attr`, and actually `**/blah/**` alone is sufficient. Thanks.